# How to print document library item from ribbon button

Tags: document-library, javascript, client-object-model, printing

I'm creating some custom features to add functionality to the ribbon.

I have created a button to print the page you are viewing very easily like that:

SPItem containing elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="Benetton_FRA.PrintPage" Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.Copies.Controls._children">
      <Button Id="Ribbon.Documents.Copies.PrintPage"
              Command="PrintPage"
              Sequence="15"
              Image16by16="/_layouts/images/Benetton_FRA/print16.gif"
              Image32by32="/_layouts/images/Benetton_FRA/print.gif"
              Description="PrintPage" LabelText="Print Page"
              TemplateAlias="o1"/>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler
      Command="PrintPage"
      CommandAction="javascript:PrintPage();"
      EnabledScript="true"/>
  </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension>
</CustomAction>
<CustomAction Id="Ribbon.Library.Actions.Scripts"
            Location="ScriptLink"
            ScriptSrc="/_layouts/Benetton_FRA/BenettonScripts.js" />
</Elements>
```

JS file with the JS method to invoke for the page print:

```
function PrintPage() {
    window.print();
}

function enable() {
   var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();
   var itemCount = CountDictionary(items);
   return (itemCount > 0);
}
```

Everything works fine. Now I must do the same thing for files: I select one file and this had to be printed. Is there something in EMCS Script that allows me to open and print a file? Is there any server side command to do that?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you found the solution?
I am also facing the same challenge.
Thanks.

**Update:**
I am facing same problem but I am able to print. Please refer [This Link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67798/how-to-open-file-in-adobe-reader-using-command-line-without-checkout-from-javasc)

Hope this link will help others too. Please let me know if you can explore more.
Thanks.